# Pandas to_datetime() with mixed input string format

Tags: python, pandas, iso8601, string-to-datetime

Among the data frames I am analysing are columns with date information. I am interested in the time information (HH:MM) and I could get that initially with `df['columnname'].dt.time`. Now we switched from the string format "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM" to ISO8601, so an examplary date string would be "2022-03-04T23:00:00+01:00".
Analysing the new data resulted in

> Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

I could reproduce this when I used a mix of both input string formats. Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd

#d = {'Timestamp': ['2022-03-05T23:00:00+01:00', '2022-03-04T20:00:00+01:00', '2022-03-04T23:00:00+01:00']} #works
#d = {'Timestamp': ['2024-09-29 10:00', '2024-04-19 21:00', '2024-04-13 13:00']}                            #works, too 
d = {'Timestamp': ['2022-03-05T23:00:00+01:00', '2022-03-04T20:00:00+01:00', '2024-04-13 13:00']}           #does not work

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df_times = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'],  errors = 'coerce')

print(df_times.dt.time)
```

Each `d` with homogeneous format works but mixed format results in the error above.
Now, I tried to use

```
df_times = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], **format='mixed'**, errors = 'coerce')
```

In this case, there is no error but every output value is `NaT`. Also in the case of homogeneous data strings.

I am confused by this behaviour because to me it seems like something in the regular scope of `to_datetime`.
Can anyone please help me understand this. I would like to get a solution with `to_datetime` working (instead of some string manipulation) because it would enable to access other date attributes later on as well.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of `format='mixed', errors = 'coerce'`, use `exact=False`

Comment: what is desired output?

Comment: Thanks, @JoshFriedlander, but for the mixed case this still yields
"AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values"

Comment: @PandaKim: The desired output is the conversion of the strings to datetime format. Since it works for each individual string format, why is there a problem for a mix of those string formats?

Comment: @croessler They are already converted to datetime.  problem is that you cannot use various methods(with `dt`)  because the dtype of the series is object since there are two timesteps. Could you please clarify what you are trying to achieve? Basic calculate operations are still possible. Try executing the following code: `print(df_times + pd.Timedelta('10min'))`
If you want to use the dt accessor, make sure to unify the time axis.

Comment: @PandaKim I get a bunch of information in a json-file and try to extract the individual parts. In this particular case, it seems that a date information is given in two different formats. I am interested in the time information of the datetime/timestamp and hope I do not need to care whether the input looks like '2024-04-13 13:00' or '2022-03-04T23:00:00+01:00'. I hope(d) I could give both formats to to_datetime and get the output for both cases in the same format (datetime) so that I can do the further processing without caring for the input format.

Comment: @croessler Using utc will result in a single data type. `df_times = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], utc=True)`

Comment: Stackoverflow says to not discuss to much in comments and I do not have enough reputation to open a chat. :D
So,
1.) Thank you very much @PandaKim, this is not ideal since I need to re-adjust the time, but it works in general and I can use it to go on.
2.) I hope the problem is clear now, so maybe we should refrain from the comment-discussion.
Cheers everyone!